# Laravel 5.5 BroadcastException with Pusher

Tags: vue.js, chat, pusher, laravel-5.5

I have create the chat application in laravel with Brodecast+Vue so when trying to my test broadcast class its getting error **"BroadcastException in PusherBroadcaster.php (line 106)"** I have double checked all configurations and api authentications are correct. but getting error and pusher debug console do not display and request.

driver :

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap1',
            'encrypted' => true
        ],
    ],
```

event :

```
public $message;
public $user;

public function __construct($message, User $user)
{
    $this->message = $message;
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

test function :

```
public function test()
{
    $user = User::find(Auth::id());
    event(new ChatEvent('Hello pusher', $user));
    return response('done');
}
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to make encrypted = false.

```
'pusher' => [
        'driver' => 'pusher',
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'options' => [
            'cluster' => 'ap1',
            'encrypted' => false
        ],
    ],
```